# Prove an inequality using Jensen's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, jensen-inequality

Let $Q\in M_1(M_1(\Sigma)),$ whereby $M_1(\Sigma)$ denotes the space of probability measures on $\Sigma.$ We define a new measure $\mu_Q (\Gamma) = \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \nu(\Gamma)Q(d\nu), \Gamma \in B_{\Sigma},$ the Borel sigma algebra on $\Sigma, \nu \in M_1(\Sigma).$ Let $V: \Sigma \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be bounded and measurable function. I need to prove the following inequality $$\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \exp[\int_{\Sigma} Vd\nu] Q(d\nu)\ \leq \int_{\Sigma} \exp[V] d\mu_Q.$$ Given that the exponential is convex, I use the Jensen's inequality to get for the inner integral, $$\exp[\int_{\Sigma} V d\nu] \leq \int_{\Sigma} \exp[V] d\nu.$$ Inserting this into the integral expression we get, $$\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \exp[\int_{\Sigma} Vd\nu] Q(d\nu)\ \leq\int_{M_1(\Sigma)}\int_{\Sigma}\exp[V] d\nu Q(d\nu).$$ I do not know how to go from here. I guess one may write $d\mu_Q = \nu Q(d\nu),$ given the integral definition of $\mu_Q.$ But inserting $Q(d\nu) = \frac{1}{\nu} d\mu_Q,$ is not providing the result. One should very probably use Fubini, but even this did not convince me how to correctly provide the final result. Can somebody help ? Thanks.

Comment: Do I infer correctly that $\Sigma$ is a Polish (i.e. completely metrizable separable space)?

Comment: Maybe the misunderstanding comes from the fact that one rather has $\mu_Q = \nu Q(d\nu)$, so that $d\mu_Q = d\nu Q(d\nu)$.

Comment: Thanks. Thats true, $\Sigma$ is assumed to be Polish. I thought, this was not relevant to mention. $\mu_Q$ is defined via the integral via the other measure, $Q(d\nu).$ Should one somehow use the Radon-Nikodym theorem? Also, how one would get rid of the outer integral over the space $M_1(\Sigma) $?

Comment: It is relevant in the sense that you want to use Borel sets, so you need some type of topology. But the argument is indeed independent of that. In my answer I try to explain that there is no need of getting rid of the outer integral. That is simply an equivalent way of writing your definition of $\mu_Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is only superficial. By that I mean that you defined $\mu_Q := \int \nu Q(d\nu)$, so that heuristically you get exactly
$$
\int fd\mu_Q = \int \int fd\nu\;Q(d\nu)\qquad\text{ for all }f\in L^1(\mu_Q).
$$
The rest of this answer is concerned with making this rigorous.

The definition of your measure immediately implies that
$$
\int_\Sigma 1_A d\mu_Q = \mu_Q(A) = \int \nu(A)\;Q(d\nu) = \int \int_\Sigma 1_A(x) d\nu(x) \;Q(d\nu).
$$
This means immediately that
$$
\int_\Sigma fd\mu_Q = \int \int_\Sigma f(x)d\nu(x)\;Q(d\nu)
$$
whenever $f$ is a simple function (i.e. $f= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k 1_{A_k}$ with $A_1,\dots, A_n$ disjoint).

From here, you continue as one did for the construction of the integral. First, you take a positive function $f$ and approximate it pointwisely (that means **everywhere** and not a.e.) by an increasing sequence of the previous simple functions $f_n$. Then, by using monotone convergence multiple times, one has
\begin{align*}
\int_\Sigma f d\mu_Q = \lim_n \int_\Sigma f_n d\mu_Q &= \lim_n \int \int_\Sigma f_n(x) d\nu(x)\; Q(d\nu) \\
&= \int \lim_n \int_\Sigma f_n(x)d\nu(x)\;Q(d\nu) \\
&= \int \int_\Sigma f(x)d\nu(x)\;Q(d\nu).
\end{align*}
For general $f\in L^1(\mu_Q)$, you consider the positive and the negative real part separately to conclude that
$$
\int fd\mu_Q = \int \int fd\nu \;Q(d\nu).
$$

Comment: Thanks. Why you need to make $L^1$ dependent on $\mu_Q$ ? I would like to better understand the heuristic approach. Based on the way $\mu_Q$ is defined as an integral, is it correct to write, $d\mu_Q = \nu Q(d\nu)$ ?

Comment: Following your heuristic approach, it seems as if one has to get $d\mu_Q = d\nu Q(d\nu).$ I am confused. May one use Radon-Nikodym's theorem ? The problem is, absolute continuity is not assumed.

Comment: @user996159 Well the Lebesgue space $L^1$ **always** depends on the measure under consideration. For example $x\mapsto 1/x$ is not in $L^1(dx)$, but it is in $L^1(\delta_1)$, where $\delta_1$ denotes the Dirac mass at 1.

Comment: I don't see in which way Radon-Nikodym would help you here. Radon-Nikodym can be applied when you have to measures on the same space such that one is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the other. But here, you want to apply it to $\mu_Q$ and $Q$? They live in completely different space. And I think, the heuristic way to think is that $\mu_Q = \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \nu\; Q(d\nu)$, which can be rewritten as $\mu_Q(dx) := \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \nu(dx) \; Q(d\nu)$. This makes it clearer with respect to which variable you "differentiate".

Comment: Great. Thanks. I also understand the rigorous approach. Coming back to the heuristic way, starting at $\int_{\Sigma}fd\mu_Q$ and accepting $d\mu_Q = d\nu Q(d\nu),$ what is the explanation to not only include the last expression in the integral but also an additional integral ? The easiest way would be if we had $d\mu_Q = \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} d\nu Q(d\nu)$. In that case the substitution would have been straightforward. Can you elaborate shortly on this ?

Comment: If you look at my last comment, that is precisely what I wrote with the only difference that I used $\mu_Q(dx)$ instead of $d\mu_Q$ to be precise on the variable. The former, which I wrote in my first comment, is not a good way to express it. I was a bit fast when I wrote that first comment.